# How to call or return the view of another controller from one controller in ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

My project structure is like:

- Controllers/PartographController.cs

  - Views/Partograph/Create.cshtml
- Controllers/BirthDetailsController.cs

  - Views/BirthDetails/Create.cshtml

Is it possible to display both create method from one controller?

Say for example I have a **PartographController** and a **Partograph/Create.cshtml** view. While in the PartographController, I can easily Create new partograph.

Now say I have a **BirthDetailsController** and a **BirthDetails/Create.cshtml** view also.

I want to show both create method from one controller but when the user input the different form and finally attempt to submit it then it effects the particular controller.

How can I do this?
Is there a good way to do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If the user inputs different data for each Controller, the best you can do is show one `<form>` depending on whether you want to create a Partograph or a BirthDetails -  you would do this in the UI with JavaScript

Comment: Can you tell me more details about this? or show me any example?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full example, but basically: 1) Create a model (class) that contains the model for both Create actions (called wrapper model). 2) Create a view that accepts the wrapper model. 3) In the view, have one `<form>` for each of the create models in the wrapper. 4) Put each form in a `<div>` and give it a meaningful `id`. 5) With JavaScript, hide one and show the other as needed (`document.getElementById("partograph-form").setAttribute("display", "hidden")` for example)

Comment: Do you want to move the two create mehod into another action?

Answer (score 0):

One of them is changing the post action URL with Javacript and direct the form to which controller you want.
I don't know if this is a good solution for you but you can show and hide 2 different forms and post them seperately.

Answer (score -1):

You could try as below in your target controller:

```
[Route("Partograph/Create")]
        public IActionResult Create1() 
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Route("BirthDetails/Create")]
        public IActionResult Create2()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

Move the two view named "Create1"and "Create2" to the target floder

**Update:**

all my codes and related and the debug result:

Models:

```
public class Model1
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class Model2
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public Model1 M1 { get; set; }
        public Model2 M2 { get; set; }

    }
```

in Home controller:

```
public IActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Route("Model1/Create")]
        public IActionResult Create1()
        {
            return View();
        }
        [Route("Model2/Create")]
        public IActionResult Create2()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

view Create:

```
@model ViewModel
<a>Create M1</a>
<form asp-controller="Model1" asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M1.Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M1.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M1.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M1.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M1.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M1.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
<a>Create M2</a>
<form asp-controller="Model2" asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M2.Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M2.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M2.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M2.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M2.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M2.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

View Create1:

```
@model ViewModel
<a>Create M1</a>
<form asp-controller="Model1" asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M1.Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M1.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M1.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M1.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M1.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M1.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

View Create2:

```
@model ViewModel
<a>Create M2</a>
<form asp-controller="Model2" asp-action="Create">
    <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M2.Id" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M2.Id" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M2.Id" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="M2.Name" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="M2.Name" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="M2.Name" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
    </div>
</form>
```

Debug Result:
[image]

in my understanding,  you want to move the  two  "Create" method into another controller,if there's any mistake in my understanding,please point it out